# PhpStorm и Git Bash (в качестве консоли), как изменить цветовую схему?

Tags: phpstorm, git-bash

Не могу разобраться, как поменять цветовую схему в терминале. Использую phpStorm+Material Theme UI(Oceanic), в качестве консоли использую git bash (в настройках выбрал: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`).

Цвета руками нигде не менял (все по дефолту), в итоге получается следующая ситуация в окне терминала:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я понять не могу, как поменять этот "вырвиглазный фон"? Пытался посмотреть в `Editor - General - Selection background`, цвета дефолтные (точно те тот, который выводиться в консоле).

Есть мысль, где можно поменять?

P.S. Использовать виндовую консоль не очень хочеться, привык к гит башу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом перебора, нашел нужную опции в настройках цветовой схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]